# Pine script : Add opacity on hline

Tags: pine-script

I want to change the opacity of the color.
I have tried transp and color.new => Error

How can I fix this?

```
band1 = hline(25, "Upper Band", color=#ff0000)
```

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `color.new()` functions has an argument for the transparency.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

color c1 = color.new(color.blue, 80)
color c2 = color.new(color.blue, 50)
color c3 = color.new(color.blue, 20)

hline(50000, color=c1, linestyle= hline.style_solid)
hline(49000, color=c2, linestyle= hline.style_solid)
hline(48000, color=c3, linestyle= hline.style_solid)
plot(close)
```

[image]